# how to remove the source column from sheet after creating the dropdown in excel

Tags: excel, validation

I have created the dropdown using data validation from other column which contains more than 30 values in excel. I need to send the excel to user to enter the data but the source field for dropdown should not be shown to user .can you please assist me how to achieve this?

Comment: Hide the sheet containing the list used for the dropdown

Comment: tq u ,it worked

Answer (score 0):

Hide the sheet containing the list used for the dropdown.
If you switch to the VBE you can even set the worksheet.Visible property as `veryHidden`: that way users can't even see it's hidden and can't unhide it.